# PHP Json Parser

Tags: php, json

I am new to PHP Programming,
I need to parse the json string.
This is the string what I have as JSON array

```
 [{"datetime":"17/02/2014 13:18:30","type":"testtype","locationid":"1","GPSType":"GOOGLE","GPSLatitude":"1.1","GPSLongtitude":"1.2","userid":"admin","brand":"1234567","numbers":["num1","num2","num3]}]
```

In the above string I need to parse numbers array only.

Comment: Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) - But make sure the JSON string is valid, else it'd return `NULL`. The JSON string you have in the question is ***not*** valid (as you can verify with an online validator such as http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: If I just [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=parse+json+with+php) then the appropriate PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is the first hit.

Comment: sorry I checked with jsonlint.com for my json and it says valid [
    {
        "datetime": "17/02/2014 13:18:30",
        "type": "testtype",
        "locationid": "1",
        "GPSType": "GOOGLE",
        "GPSLatitude": "1.1",
        "GPSLongtitude": "1.2",
        "userid": "admin",
        "brand": "1234567",
        "numbers": [
            "num1",
            "num2",
            "num3"
        ]
    }
]

Comment: @user3323251 — There is a `"` in that comment that isn't in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are having JSON string in your PHP code.
There is an error in your JSON string.
Since you are maintaining your JSON string as an array, you may follow this approach.
You can understand this easily.

```
<?php
    $json = '[
                {
                    "datetime": "17/02/2014 13:18:30",
                    "type": "testtype",
                    "locationid": "1",
                    "GPSType": "GOOGLE",
                    "GPSLatitude": "1.1",
                    "GPSLongtitude": "1.2",
                    "userid": "admin",
                    "brand": "1234567",
                    "numbers": ["num1", "num2", "num3"]
                }
            ]';

    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $len = count($obj[0]->{'numbers'});
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        echo $obj[0]->{'numbers'}[$i].'<br>';
    }
    ?>
```

The Output would be:

> num1 
>   num2 
>   num3

Answer (score -1):

As others have mentioned in the comments, use `json_decode`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

[EDIT]

In order to get only the `"numbers"` array, simply try this:

```
$json = json_decode($input, true);
$numbers = $json[0]["numbers"];
```

The `json_decode` function will convert your JSON string to an associative array, from which you can just get the indices you need.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Please read the first half of the answer and ask yourself: is this a "link only answer"?

Comment: The answer provides all the information the OP has requested: a way to parse JSON strings in PHP. Plus a link to the documentation. I fail to see the problem.